# Problems with my prototype of kernel (x86_64)

Tags: gcc, assembly, kernel, x86-64, osdev

I'm trying to learn how a kernel works while I learn assembly, and in the duty of learning how to successfully create a bootable x86_64 kernel, I had a problem:
I tried to successfully output some text with functions in "main.c" (all the files below) by using the VGA buffer in `0xB8000`, the same way that I did with the 32 bits version of the kernel prototype, but the difference is that the start files are different.
The problem here is that when I use the exact same functions for the 32 bits version, it successfully prints to the screen, but when using the new files to reach the long mode (`multiboot.S` and `start.S`) this doesn't happen, the screen just go black when testing in qemu and after a few seconds it crashes with the error message:

```
warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x00000000000a0000
```

Why this happens? The VGA buffer just isn't in `0xB8000`, There is something wrong with the *.S files? Thanks in advance!
I will paste here the kernel files:
The kernel is composed of 4 files: "main.c", "start.S", "multiboot.S" and the linker script, "linker.ld".
This 3 files are linked and compiled without any error, the files are the following: This is main.c (you will see a "basiccolors.h", this file just define vga color codes)

```
#include "basiccolors.h"
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

volatile uint16_t* vga_buffer = (uint16_t*)0xB8000; /* memory location of the VGA textmode buffer */
/* Columns and rows of the VGA buffer */
const int VGA_COLS = 80; 
const int VGA_ROWS = 25;

/* We start displaying text in the top-left of the screen (column = 0, row = 0) */
int term_col = 0;
int term_row = 0;
uint8_t term_color = WHITE_TXT; /* This color and others are defined in basiccolors.h */

/* term_init() : This function initiates the terminal by clearing it */
void term_init()
{
    /* Clear the textmode buffer */
    for (int col = 0; col < VGA_COLS; col ++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < VGA_ROWS; row ++)
        {
            /* The VGA textmode buffer has size (VGA_COLS * VGA_ROWS) */
            /* Given this, we find an index into the buffer for our character */
            const size_t index = (VGA_COLS * row) + col;
            /* Entries in the VGA buffer take the binary form BBBBFFFFCCCCCCCC, where: */
            /* - B is the background color */
            /* - F is the foreground color */
            /* - C is the ASCII character */
            /*  Now we set the character to blank (a space character)   */          
        vga_buffer[index] = ((uint16_t)term_color << 8) | ' '; 
        }
    }
}

/* term_putc(char c) : This function places a single character onto the  screen */
void term_putc(char c)
{
    /* We don't want to display all characters, for example, the newline ones */
    switch (c)
    {
    case '\n': /* Newline characters should return the column to 0, and increment the row */
        {
            term_col = 0;
            term_row ++;
            break;
        }

    default: /* Normal characters just get displayed and then increment the column */
        {
        /* Like before, calculate the buffer index */           
        const size_t index = (VGA_COLS * term_row) + term_col; 
        vga_buffer[index] = ((uint16_t)term_color << 8) | c;
        term_col ++;
        break;
        }
    }

/* We need to reset the column to 0, and increment the row to get to a new line */
    if (term_col >= VGA_COLS)
    {
        term_col = 0;
        term_row ++;
    }

/* we get past the last row, so we need to reset both column and row to 0 in order to loop back to the top of the screen */
    if (term_row >= VGA_ROWS)
    {
        term_col = 0;
        term_row = 0;
    }
   }

/* term_print : prints an entire string onto the screen, remember to use the "\n" and that short of things */
void term_print(const char* str)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i ++) /* Keep placing characters until we hit the null-terminating character ('\0') */
        term_putc(str[i]);
}
/* Main function of the kernel, the one that is called at the end of the loading */
void kmain(void)
{
    /* Now we should initialize the interfaces */
    term_init(); /* VGA basic interface, in "basicoutput.c/h" */
    term_print("CKA Cobalt release                                                      [0-0-1]\n");
};
```

This is start.S:

```
    .extern kmain

    .section .data

    .align 16
gdtr:
gdtr_limit:
    .word (global_descriptor_table_end - global_descriptor_table) - 1
gdtr_pointer:
    .int global_descriptor_table

    .global global_descriptor_table
global_descriptor_table:
null_descriptor:
    .quad 0x0000000000000000
code_descriptor:
    .quad 0x0020980000000000
data_descriptor:
    .quad 0x0000900000000000
global_descriptor_table_end:

    .global null_segment
    .set null_segment, (null_descriptor - global_descriptor_table)
    .global code_segment
    .set code_segment, (code_descriptor - global_descriptor_table)
    .global data_segment
    .set data_segment, (data_descriptor - global_descriptor_table)

multiboot_magic:
    .space 4
multiboot_info:
    .space 4

    .section .bss

    .global kernel_pagetable
    .align 0x1000
kernel_pagetable:
pml4:
    .space 0x1000
pdpt:
    .space 0x1000
pd:
    .space 0x1000
kernel_pagetable_end:

    .global kernel_stack
kernel_stack:
    .space 0x1000
kernel_stack_end:

    .section .text
    .code32

    .global start

start:
    cli

# store multiboot parameters in .data
    mov %eax, multiboot_magic
    mov %ebx, multiboot_info

# zerofill .bss
    cld
    mov $bss, %edi
    mov $bss_end, %ecx
    sub %edi, %ecx
    xor %eax, %eax
    rep stosb

# create pagetable for identity mapping lower 2 megabytes
# make minimal page table entries
    .set pml4_entry, (pdpt + 0x03)
    .set pdpt_entry, (pd + 0x03)
    .set pd_entry, 0b10000011
    movl $pml4_entry, pml4
    movl $pdpt_entry, pdpt
    movl $pd_entry, pd

# setup long mode
# load global descriptor table
    lgdt (gdtr)

# enable Physical Address Extension (PAE)
    mov %cr4, %eax
    bts $5, %eax
    mov %eax, %cr4

# set up page table
    mov $kernel_pagetable, %eax
    mov %eax, %cr3

# set up long mode
    .set EFER_MSR_ADDRESS, 0xC0000080
    mov $EFER_MSR_ADDRESS, %ecx
    rdmsr
    bts $8, %eax
    wrmsr

# enable paging
    mov %cr0, %eax
    bts $31, %eax
    mov %eax, %cr0

# long jump to set code segment
    ljmp $code_segment, $longmode_start

    .code64
longmode_start:
# data segment selector to all data segments
    mov $data_segment, %bx
    mov %bx, %ds
    mov %bx, %es
    mov %bx, %fs
    mov %bx, %gs

# null segment selector to ss
    mov $null_segment, %bx
    mov %bx, %ss

# set up kernel stack
    mov $kernel_stack_end, %rsp
    push $0     # debugger backtrace stops here

# call kmain
    mov multiboot_magic, %edi
    mov multiboot_info, %esi
    call kmain

# hang the computer
    cli
hang:
    hlt
    jmp hang
```

This is multiboot.S:

```
    .set MULTIBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN, 1 << 0
    .set MULTIBOOT_MEM_INFO, 1 << 1
    .set MULTIBOOT_AOUT_KLUDGE, 1 << 16
    .set MULTIBOOT_MAGIC, 0x1BADB002
    .set MULTIBOOT_FLAGS, MULTIBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN | MULTIBOOT_MEM_INFO | MULTIBOOT_AOUT_KLUDGE
    .set MULTIBOOT_CHECKSUM, -(MULTIBOOT_MAGIC + MULTIBOOT_FLAGS)

    .section .mboot
    .align 4

    .global multiboot_header

multiboot_header:
    .int MULTIBOOT_MAGIC
    .int MULTIBOOT_FLAGS
    .int MULTIBOOT_CHECKSUM
    .int multiboot_header
    .int text
    .int data_end
    .int kernel_end
    .int start
```

And this is my linker.ld:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(start)

phys = 0x0100000;

SECTIONS
{
    . = phys;
    kernel_start = .;

    .text ALIGN(4096) : AT( ADDR(.text) )
    {
        text = .;
        *(.mboot)  /* Put Multiboot header section in the beginning of .text section */
        *(.text)
        *(.rodata)
        text_end = .;
    }

    .data ALIGN(4096) : AT( ADDR(.data) )
    {
        data = .;
        *(.data)
        data_end = .;
    }

    .bss ALIGN(4096) : AT( ADDR(.bss) )
    {
        bss = .;
        *(.bss)
        bss_end = .;
    }

    kernel_end = .;
}
```

All this code is compilled and linked with the following commands:
Compiling...

```
x86_64-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -mcmodel=large -mno-red-zone -mno-mmx -mno-sse -mno-sse2 -c <file> -o <object-file>
```

And linking:

```
x86_64-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -T linker.ld multiboot.o start.o main.o -o kernel.bin -nostdlib -lgcc
```

This commands are suggested by osdev.com in the tutorial http://wiki.osdev.org/Creating_a_64-bit_kernel and all is compiled and linked using a gcc cross-compiler for the x86_64 architecture.

Comment: Before trying to write a kernel, you might want to learn how to use debuggers. For low level stuff I recommend bochs, not qemu.

Comment: @Jester Ok, I will take a look to bochs right now

Comment: If your version of Bochs doesn't have 64-bit support you can build it with such support from the sources. OS Dev Wiki has more information on Bochs and how to build an x86-64 enabled version: http://wiki.osdev.org/Bochs#Compiling_Bochs_from_Source

Comment: I'm curious how you are running this. Do you build an ISO (with something like grub-mkrescue) and boot with Grub2 and running it in QEMU?

Comment: @MichaelPetch qemu can launch a multiboot image directly, I assume that's what he is doing.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I link all to a .bin file and then I run it with the command qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel kernel.bin

Comment: @Jester : QEMU doesn't support elf64 executables with the `-kernel` parameter or at least it didn't so in the recent past. It use to be that only elf32 would work with `-kernel`

Comment: @MichaelPetch acording to what you say about the support of elf64 files in qemu, I guess that I should try it with a disk image, I will do it now.

Comment: @MichaelPetch When booting the disk image made with grub-mkrescue grub gives me the error "no multiboot header found" despite that the kernel have one, booting with both protocols, multiboot and multiboot2. If you want I can upload the .iso so you or anyone can test it.

Comment: No, now that you are that far the issue is that you need to make a multiboot2 compliant header. I'm assuming in your grub.cfg that you used the `multiboot2` directive to load your kernel.bin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QEMU doesn't support *ELF64* executables when using the `-kernel` parameter. You will need to boot your kernel with a multiboot2 compatible loader like *GRUB2* . Unfortunately you will also need to change your multiboot header to be [multiboot2 compliant](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot2/multiboot.html). You can replace your `multiboot.S` file to be:

```
.section .mboot
.code32
.align 8

    # constants for multiboot2 header:
    .set MAGIC2,    0xe85250d6
    .set ARCH2,     0                  # i386 protected mode
    .set CHECKSUM2, (-(MAGIC2 + ARCH2 + (mboot2_end - mboot2_start)) & 0xffffffff)

     /* multiboot2 header */
mboot2_start:
    .long MAGIC2
    .long ARCH2
    .long mboot2_end - mboot2_start
    .long CHECKSUM2
    .word  0                           # type
    .word  0                           # flags
    .long  8                           # size
mboot2_end:
```

You compile it the same way you did before. There is a catch - in order to make sure this header doesn't end up being pushed beyond the first 8kb of the file you'll likely need to specify 4kb pages when you link:

```
x86_64-elf-gcc -z max-page-size=0x1000 -ffreestanding -T linker.ld \
    multiboot.o start.o main.o -o kernel.bin -nostdlib -lgcc
```

The addition of the `-z max-page-size=0x1000` forces the maximum page size to 4kb.

Comment: It works now, thanks for the patience and the answer.

Comment: I have cleaned it up for one last time (hopefully). I originally took a header I found online and realized it is just lucky that it works. I've simplified it down to the basics. I've completely removed the unnecessary stuff and fixed a bug in the structure.